# arcpy.env.overwriteOutput() not working with arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion()?

Tags: arcpy

I have created a simple model to transfer multiple feature classes to a shapefile. With the model I exported a .py script which I'd like to run with my task manager to update any changes each day. 
The script that runs with out overwriting:

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Local variables:
adverse = "F:\\Atco_gis\\temp_shapefiles\\LP_Layers_Temp.gdb\\adverse"
comments = "F:\\Atco_gis\\temp_shapefiles\\LP_Layers_Temp.gdb\\comments"
desig_crossing = "F:\\Atco_gis\\temp_shapefiles\\LP_Layers_Temp.gdb\\desig_crossing"
Temp_LP_Layers = "F:\\Atco_gis\\temp_shapefiles\\Temp_LP_Layers"
Temp_LP_Layers__2_ = Temp_LP_Layers

# Process: Feature Class To Shapefile (multiple)
arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion("F:\\Atco_gis\\temp_shapefiles\\LP_Layers_Temp.gdb\\adverse;F:\\Atco_gis\\temp_shapefiles\\LP_Layers_Temp.gdb\\comments;F:\\Atco_gis\\temp_shapefiles\\LP_Layers_Temp.gdb\\desig_crossing", Temp_LP_Layers)
```

I have been reading that:

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
```

should solve the problem however it leaves me with a new output with _1 or _2 depending how many times the script has been ran.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, are you putting the arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True statement before the arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion() statement?

Comment: You could delete the old before writing the new.

Comment: That works in ModelBuilder, because ModelBuilder runs inside of an ArcMap session that is active where those environment variables apply.  The Environment variables only work for the Python Window, not scripts.  Python and arcpy scripts run without any connection to an ArcMap session, so the Environment variables of ArcMap have no effect.  You should always test to see if the file exists and then delete it when it does with: if arcpy.Exists(File): arcpy.Delete_management(File)

Comment: @RichardFairhurst I use the overwrite environment all the time in scripts?

Comment: It has never worked for me in a standalone script.  After trying it on multiple occasions and having it screw up my scripts consistently, I have always used the test and delete code I mentioned.

Comment: @RichardFairhurst I use `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput` in many standalone scripts successfully but I have found odd tools which appear not to respect it.  That should be documented in the Environment section of the Help for those tools, but I think is not always.

Comment: Potentially the reason I no longer ever would consider using the overwrite option is that it has been a few years since any of my scripts used geoprocessing tools exclusively like ModelBuilder.  Virtually all of my scripts have been converted to use cursors and dictionaries instead of geoprocessing tools to do all of my data summaries, comparisons and manipulation, so the Exists and Delete_management process is the only option for the kinds of scripts I now write.  My scripts now perform 100 times faster than any script that uses a geoprocessing approach, so there is no going back for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Feature Class To Shapefile tool is a Python Script Tool and you can see its source by locating it in the Search Window and right-clicking it to choose Edit from its context menu.

It is this code, in particular a function named `ConversionUtils.GenerateOutputName` that appears to be generating the names with `_1`, `_2`, etc (depending how many times the script has been run) appended to them.

This behaviour is mentioned in the [Feature Class To Shapefile Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/feature-class-to-shapefile.htm) and that is what bypasses your setting for `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput`:

> If the output shapefile already exists in the Output Folder, a number
>   will be appended to the end to make the shapefile name unique (for
>   example, rivers_1.shp).

I would not recommend trying to change the source for this tool, and I think you will find it very difficult to try and copy the source and edit it to create a new tool.

Instead I recommend doing as [@Aaron suggested in a comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308260/simple-output-overwrite-not-working#comment499080_308260) and write some code, to insert before you run `arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion()`, which deletes existing copies of any shapefiles before recreate them.

That code would involve using the `arcpy.Exists()` and `arcpy.Delete_management()` functions, along with some string manipulation of the pathnames to your output shapefiles.